# How do I load fonts with filenames which begin with numbers, via the FontFace interface in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, interface, safari, font-face

I can't get Safari(11.1) to load font files via the FontFace interface, **if those <s>files</s> font names begin with numbers.**

The same files that show an error in Safari load perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox. Here is the most simplified version I could create that still produces the error.

```
var fonty = new FontFace('0Test', 'url(fonts/0Test.woff)');

console.log('This will only show if the Font name does not begin with a number');
```

Checking the Safari(11.1 is the version I'm using) console, you'll see the error: 'SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.', and when actual valid fonts that begin with numbers are used, it simply won't load.

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue https://jsfiddle.net/0oknd7eL/1/

Is there a workaround to this situation, that still uses the FontFace interface?

**Edit** - To clarify, the issue is with the names of the fonts, and not the names of the files. For example `FontFace('012-This-Beginning-With-Numbers-Is-The-Issue', 'url(fonts/012-This-Seems-Fine.woff)');`

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but are you sure it's the filename and not the font name itself it complains about?

Comment: Thank you, I should have clarified. It IS the font name that it complains about. Code written as `var fonty = new FontFace('Lettersonly', 'url(fonts/123Test.woff)');` will pass through(although obviously not load a font). But a code like `var fonty = new FontFace('123Test', 'url(fonts/Lettersonly.woff)');` will not.