# CSS @font-face with a number

Tags: css

I've narrowed down the problem to any font that has the file with a number, but I cannot figure out a solution without renaming the file.

So for example `0 font.ttf` will not work while `font.ttf` works perfectly fine.

My attempts, none of which successful:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "0 font";
  src: url("0 font.ttf");
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 0 font;
  src: url(0 font.ttf);
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "\0 font";
  src: url("\0 font.ttf");
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: \0 font;
  src: url(\0 font.ttf);
}
```

Comment: @Adrian Brand that is not my question unfortunately, and not a viable solution for my case.

Comment: Did you try to replace the space by an underscore ?

Comment: @MaxiGui I did not, however, other font files with spaces in them worked fine. I cannot alter the font file name in any way.

Comment: ` src: url(0%20font.ttf);` try with `%20`

Comment: Here some similar problem, It seems to come from the font-family name:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639922/how-do-i-load-fonts-with-filenames-which-begin-with-numbers-via-the-fontface-in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951584/assigning-a-css-fontfamily-ending-with-a-number

Comment: @MaxiGui that solved it! Thank you! I guess I should've tried single quotes as well as double.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [assigning a CSS fontFamily ending with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951584/assigning-a-css-fontfamily-ending-with-a-number)